Salesforce metadata api error- Cannot find the declaration of element while inserting custom fields in case object
I was trying to add multiple fields in the case object using the Salesforce metadata API. I created an SFDX: Create Project with Manifest.
Then, with folder structure force-app\main\default\objects\case, I created a .XML file to create multiple fields for the case object.
Then, got the error " cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'CustomObject'.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomObject xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <label>Case</label>
    <fields>
        <fullName>Net_Promoter_Score__c</fullName>
        <label>Net Promoter Score</label>
        <type>Number</type>
        <precision>2</precision>
        <scale>0</scale>
    </fields>
    <fields>
        <fullName>Product_Satisfaction__c</fullName>
        <label>Product Satisfaction</label>
        <type>Picklist</type>
        <picklist>
            <picklistValues>
                <fullName>Very Satisfied</fullName>
                <default>false</default>
            </picklistValues>
            <picklistValues>
                <fullName>Satisfied</fullName>
                <default>false</default>
            </picklistValues>
            <picklistValues>
                <fullName>Neutral</fullName>
                <default>false</default>
            </picklistValues>
        </picklist>
    </fields>
    <fields>
        <fullName>Service_Rating__c</fullName>
        <label>Service Rating</label>
        <type>Picklist</type>
        <picklist>
            <picklistValues>
                <fullName>Excellent</fullName>
                <default>false</default>
            </picklistValues>
            <picklistValues>
                <fullName>Good</fullName>
                <default>false</default>
            </picklistValues>
            <picklistValues>
                <fullName>Average</fullName>
                <default>false</default>
            </picklistValues>
        </picklist>
    </fields>
</CustomObject>




Pretty sure this is a false positive, and that you can safely ignore it.
